# Which version of netCDF contains libnetcdf.so.6?

Tags: netcdf

It's all in the title.

I have version 4.1.3 installed, and that contains `libnetcdf.so.7`.

Is this question a better fit for a different SE site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 4.1.1 contains `libnetcdf.so.6`.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @KenY-N what's left to be said?

Comment: @KenY-N i guess this question and answer have accomplished at least one thing: they've revealed that the bot you're using is buggy.